# logic error in dijkstra's algorithm involving 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, logic, dijkstra

my project was to create a python program which would use dijkstra's shortest path algorithm on a set of nodes that the user can input, the idea was that i would be able to do it on any size map that the user inputs.
however i haven't gotten very far into it because i encountered an error near the beginning.

```
#if user wants a small map i.e. less than 27 nodes, the nodes will be named differently to if it is a large map
global array_type
#creates the list
node_list=[]
node_array=[]
#makes sure the user only inputs a valid number of nodes
def check_int(x):
    while True:
        try:
            #checks if node is integer
            int(x)
            #checks if node is negative
            if int(x)<1:
                #if it is, then it changes it to'x'
                x='x'
                #this means that it is picked up as a value error and passed to the except
                int(x)
            #returns the number of nodes if it is valid
            return(x)
        except ValueError:
            print('only a whole positive number of nodes')
            x= input('how many nodes in your map?   ')

node_no= input('how many nodes in your map?   ')
node_no=check_int(node_no)
#if there are less than 27 nodes then they can be labled a, b, c...
if int(node_no) < 27:
    #creates a list with all the nodes in
    for i in range(int(node_no)):
        node_list.append(chr(int(i)+65))
        node_array.append(node_list)
    array_type=1
    #this is what the node list should stay the entire time
    print('node list=' + str(node_list))
#if there are more than 26 nodes then they will be labled a1, a2, a3...
elif int(node_no) >26:
    #creates a list with all the nodes in
    for i in range(int(node_no)):
        node_list.append('A' + str(i+1))
        node_array.append(node_list)
    array_type=2
    print('node list=' + str(node_list))
#creates a 2d array
for i in range(len(node_list)):
    for i2 in range(len(node_list)):
        #the error is here
        #for some reason this line changes the values inside 'node_list'
        #as you can see there is nowhere that i am redifining node_list
        #have i used incorrect syntax? or is this just an incorrect method to do what i want?
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
        node_array[i][i2]=str(node_list[i])+str(node_list[i2])
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
        print('node list='+str(node_list))
        print('node array='+str(node_array))
```

if you input the value of 2, then what i want is for the array to look like this:

[['AA','AB'], ['BA','BB']]

but it comes out as this:

[['AABAA', 'AABAAB'], ['AABAA', 'AABAAB']]

and for a value of 3 it should look like this:

[['AA','AB','AC'], ['BA,'BB','BC'], ['CA','CB','CC']]

but instead it looks like this:

[['AABAABAACAABAA', 'AABAABAACAABAAB', 'AABAABAACAABAABAAC'], ['AABAABAACAABAA', 'AABAABAACAABAAB', 'AABAABAACAABAABAAC'], ['AABAABAACAABAA', 'AABAABAACAABAAB', 'AABAABAACAABAABAAC']]

the reason i want this is so that every cell in the array represents a different journey, i would then ask to see which nodes you can reach from which (not intending to do directions yet, this will allow the user to define the weight of each link.

i spent a couple hours researching this problem to make sure that i didnt just use the wrong syntax but i wasnt able to find anything that would help, although it is possible that i was searching for the wrong thing.

if you are able to solve the problem i have been having or provide an alternate solution then i would be very grateful, i know that it is best to not use try/except and global variables i am mainly focusing on getting something that works before making it as efficient as posible.

Answer (score 1):

Since `node_list` has been made a part of `node_array`, modifying `node_array` will modify `node_list` too. If you don't want this to happen, you can take a copy of `node_list`, for example with `node_list[:]`.

Here is a simple example of what is happening:

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l2 = [l,l]
>>> l
[1, 2]
>>> l2
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
>>> l2[0][1]=3
>>> l
[1, 3]
```

Comment: thankyou, i was able to solve the problem i had :) but unfortunately it led directly to another error, i feel that it would be better to ask it as an entirely new question though, thanks for the answer